# How to select element in previous <TD> in watir?

Tags: ruby, html-table, watir

I have a issue with Watir.
In UI, there are many table like below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        ABCD
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to search if "ABCD" exist in the UI or not, if exist, then select a value like "2" in droplist
Tried in this way, but didn't work well

```
puts b.td(:text => "ABCD").exist?
puts b.td(:ABCD").parent.row(:index, 0)
```

There is another table like below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option value="ABCD">ABCD</option>
            <option value="EFGH">EFGH</option>
            <option value="IJKL">IJKL</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Same requirement: search if "ABCD" exist in the UI or not, if exist, then select a value like "2" in droplist
Tried in this way, based on the way you show me, didn't work well

```
if b.td(:text, "ABCD").present?
    b.td(:text, "ABCD").parent.select_list.select('2')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something based on "ABCD" appearing, then you need to use an `if` statement (not just check if it exists). As well, you probably want to check that the element is `present?` and not just `exist?`. `exist?` only checks that the element is in the DOM and does not check that the element is actually displayed to the user (for more details you can see [this blog post](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/checking-for-an-element-exists-visible-present/)).

```
if b.td(:text => "ABCD").present?
  # Do something when the element is displayed
end
```

The previous td element is called a sibling and there are a [couple of options](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-locate-an-element-based-on-its-siblings). We can use the `parent` method as you had tried. However, note that the `parent` method already returns the row element (as it is the parent of the td). To locate the select list:

```
b.td(:text => "ABCD").parent.select_list
```

Putting it all together:

```
if b.td(:text => "ABCD").present?
    b.td(:text => "ABCD").parent.select_list.select('2')
end
```